# How to integrate images folder hierarchical with CSV file?

Tags: sql, azure, image-processing, azure-sql-database, web-development-server

Probably I could not ask the question in a proper way. But Here is what I want to do.
I have folders in hierarchical manner. Folders within folders. (For example - I am working on a DL project. I have images of blades of a image. Every fan is in one separate room of a house. House has many rooms hence we have assign number to these fans. A Fan has room number, A Blade of fan has three sides. We have assign some characters to these sides of blade also. like this we have images of blade and folders is something like this.

House - Room - Blade side

Now I want to build a front end which has these tabs(House name, room number, blade side etc) on web page . And I want to use local system's or azure storage drive to store the huge image dataset. But I want to use SQL database to store the information (like sides of the blade, room number, fan number etc) in csv format. And use this SQL as backend database for the web page.

When a user enters just any one of these information in the tab on webpage. I want this to give image as output

How to do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You could firstly build the table to store the image path. According the user condition to filter the image path, then pass the path to the blob storage or file system to get the output.

Comment: Thank you. One confirmation. Should I pass the path to the blob storage or Pass the path of blob storage into csv?

Comment: Hi @AI Lab, I would suggest you pass the path to blob storage wildcard path to get the output image which user expect.

Comment: Ok. I will try that. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. May I post it as answer? You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @AI Lab, do you get any progresses or have any other concerns?

Comment: Hello @LeonYue, Thank you for following up with me for this case. Its been few days I did not go to office due to covid19 restrictions. I can confirm you on Monday if your answer is correct and Was I able to get it done or not....!

But Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome, waiting for your good news!